Error while run " kubectl apply -f hello-world.yaml " command in ubuntu
error: error validating "hello-world.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "http://localhost:8080/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
Solution for the problem

You need to configure your local Kubernetes environment to reach the Kubernetes cluster.  How exactly to do this depends on what that cluster is.

Install Minikube to solve this Issue.

curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube && rm minikube-linux-amd64
minikube start
kubectl get po -A
alias kubectl="minikube kubectl --"

<-------Run the code to check, if same above error is repeate or not ------>

minikube dashboard

